# How to build a HTTP GET operation that accepts an array of objects from URI parameters?

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-core, url

I am trying to write a search operation that accepts multiple search objects/query objects. So, by hitting the endpoint once, you could call it with one color/shape/texture, a second color/shape/texture, etc. This would be easy to implement as a POST, but I am not sure how to do this as a GET.

So far I have written an endpoint something like this:

```
[HttpGet("search")]
public async Task<List<ResultModel>> Search([FromQuery] QueryModel[] queries)
```

However, this does not play nice with swagger, so I am not sure how to call it and I am not sure if it works. Is there any good practice for going about this/formatting the uri parameters and writing the endpoint?

Comment: You'll want to base64 encode or URL encode your queries in some way. There are bound to be things in the query string that aren't URL safe without the encoding and you'll end up with weird behavior. Encode your query string, pass it in as a string, and decode and deserialize in the method itself

Comment: Is this standard? I am afraid it would obfuscate how to consume the API.

Comment: What's your expected URL format?